# Stanford part-of-speech tagger cannot tag parentheses and quotation marks in pre-tokenized text

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, part-of-speech

I have a pre-tokenized text as the input to Stanford part-of-speech tagger. It cannot tag parentheses and quotation marks correctly at all. I don't want Stanford Tagger's default tokenization, so I disabled it, using `-tokenize false` option.

I know we should `escape characters` the way the `Penn Treebank` does during tokenization, such as turning parentheses into `-LRB-` and `-RRB-`, which is supported in [standalone Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#q).

Is there a way to nicely handle it in Stanford part-of-speech tagger?

Comment: Can you put your code, an example of input, the output you get and the output you would like to get, please?